# The divide and conquer problem algorithms

Tags: haskell

a - O(n^(log_3 4))
b - Theta(n log n)
c - Theta(n^2).

d - O(n)

e - Theta(n^(log_4 3))

Comment: This question might be more suited for https://cstheory.stackexchange.com. Also you might want to consider rephrasing your question as how can I calculate the time complexity of this divide and conquer algorithm, and less like can someone give me the correct multiple choice answer.

Comment: When asking about homework (1) **Be aware of your school policy**: asking here for help may constitute cheating. (2) Specify that the question is homework. (3) **Make a good faith attempt** to solve the problem yourself first (include your code in your question). (4) **Ask about a specific problem** with your existing implementation; see [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Also, [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) is guidance on asking homework questions.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially your problem is a recurrence relationship like this;

`T(n) = 5*T(n/3) + Theta(n^2)`

You can use what is called the [Master Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem_(analysis_of_algorithms))
to get an answer for this.

Your parameters are: `a:=3 b:=5 and f(n):=n^2`. I'm sure from here you can solve your question and get your answer.